# How Can I Align a Text Using execCommand

Tags: javascript

when I want to make a selected text as Bold , I should use this code :

```
edit.document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
```

But how can i make the align of the text is right , left or center using execCommand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

execCommand cannot be used for aligning the elements on the page. 
However you may take a look at commands like
Justify or Indent if it will serve your purpose

```
edit.document.execCommand("JustifyRight", false, "");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/